# Showing a span that has been dynamically added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I asked a question in relation to adding a click event to dynamically added elements and I learned to use `on()` to enable event delagation. However I'm still having an issue targeting the dynamically created content. Specifically a `span` with a class `desc`.

This is where I add the dynamic content:

```
$('#jobs-list-2').append("<p><span class='job_title'>" + title + "</span><span class='job_title'>" + ", " + location + "</span><br/><span>" + "Department: " + dept + "</span></p>");
$('#jobs-list-2').append("<p class='desc'><span>" + description + "</span></p>");
$('#jobs-list-2').append("<span class='details_btn'>Click for Details</span>");
```

I then assign a `click` event to the  `details_btn` class:

```
$('#jobs-list-2').on("click", ".details_btn", function () {
      $(this).parent().closest('.desc').show();   
});
```

However it doesn't seem to find an element with this class and nothing  is shown. I'm not sure how I could go about fixing this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Might not fix it, but swapping your apostrophes and speech marks in your append function would be a good step. `class='myClass'` would be classed as invalid by the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). Consistency is your friend. I personally try to make sure all JS strings are done with apostrophes.

Comment: also try it with the id for details_btn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.prev` to find the closest previous sibling that matches `.desc`:

```
$('#jobs-list-2').on("click", ".details_btn", function () {
      $(this).prev('.desc').show();   
});
```

Your code doesn't work because `$.closest` traverses the DOM *upwards* - `$(this).parent().closest('.desc')` means "Find the closest `.desc` ancestor of the current element's parent".

`$(this).prev('.desc.')` means "Starting from the current element, work backwards through siblings. Select the first that matches `.desc`."

Comment: I'm doing that and it's showing but because I've 16 buttons it's showing all 16 .desc

Comment: No, that's great thanks! I should have made it clearer in my OP

Answer (score 2):

when you say

```
$(this).parent().closest('.desc').show();
```

it would look for an element that is hirarchly higher than #jobs-list-2. so you need to enter

```
$(this).siblings('.desc').show()
```

to find the [sibling](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) of the clicked element

hope this helped.

greetings timmi

Answer (score 1):

something like this? i changed the structure a little of the html and initially hid the description span using `style="display:none;"`.  also, by switching the html around a butting the click descriptions span inside the paragraph `.desc`, you didnt need to finick with `.parent()` or anything like that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var title = "TITLE HERE";
    var location = "THIS IS THE LOCATION";
    var dept = "something about DEPT";
    var description = "im describing something";
    $('#jobs-list-2').append("<p><span class='job_title'>" + title + "</span><span class='job_title'>" + ", " + location + "</span><br/><span>" + "Department: " + dept + "</span></p>");
    $('#jobs-list-2').append("<p class='desc'><span class='description' style='display:none;'>" + description + "</span><br/><span class='details_btn'>Click for Details</span></p>");
    
    $('#jobs-list-2').on("click", ".details_btn", function () {
        console.log('click');
        $(this).closest('.desc').find('.description').show();   
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jobs-list-2">
</div>
```

Comment: I should point out that these elements are in a loop, there is 16 in total, so doing what you suggested works but multiplied by 16. Thanks anyways

Comment: Please at least state what you've changed. Did you test it yourself?

Comment: @JamieBarker i literally just edited it, and yes i did test it

Comment: @indubitablee And I literally just revoked my -1 ;D

Answer (score 0):

From your `.append()`, it seems like you are appending the `.desc` as a child of -`#job-list-2` and trying to find it as parent of it. So you should update your selector as:

```
$('#jobs-list-2').on("click", ".details_btn", function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.desc').show();   
});
```

So once you click the `.details_btn`, parent of it will be `#job-list-2` and `.desc` is child of it not parent. `.closest()` looks for parents of the given element.

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qbf4q2m1/